# Does Aptitude package manager also need the dependencies and repositories needed by APT to install software?

Tags: package-management, aptitude

I was installing software using aptitude, which is similar to APT but has a more extensive user interface.

I was wondering if aptitude package manager also needs the repositories to install the software or it is pre located.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`aptitude` is just kind of an extended command-line frontend for `apt`. It uses the same functionality internally, so both manage the exactly same packaging system with the same available repositories.

There is no difference if you have installed a package through `apt` or `aptitude`.